# Shrinking the SYSTEM tablespace in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, shrink, datafile

Our `SYSTEM` tablespace grew out of control because of the `SYS.AUD$` table.

We have truncated `SYS.AUD$` but the datafile is still very big (~30G).

Resize doesn't work because the file contains used data beyond requested `RESIZE` value

What should I do here?

Here's our version information:

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
- PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
- CORE  11.2.0.1.0  Production
- TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
- NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? Did you try Googling for a solution as there is lots of information out there.

Comment: As @Colin'tHart said, this is a common problem with mis-managed databases. Edit your question with version information

Comment: Sorry, you should recreate the dabatase. Don t forget to immediately move the AUD$ to another tablespace.

Answer (score 1):

Query the DBA_EXTENTS view to see what objects are present towards the end of the data files. It is possible that they are not system objects, or are system objects which can be safely modified so that they are towards the beginning of the files.

However I suspect that you have a big problem here -- you may be looking at creating a new database and moving all your user objects to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use segment advisor in Enterprise Manager and same can be done using PLSQL also. You can find a detailed guide in link given below:-

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10595/schema003.htm

Comment: The reorganization of this object cannot be performed online. Cannot perform online reorganization of tables owned by SYS.